# How can I tell if Office Web Apps is installed on a SharePoint 2010 server

Tags: 2010, office-web-apps

I'm supposed to install SharePoint 2010 SP2 on our SharePoint farm. It's a simple setup, there's only one web server in the farm.

My issue is that I am unsure on whether Office Web Apps was installed on this web server. I need to know so that I can determine whether I need to install [SP2 for Office Web Apps](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39659) on the server.

How can I determine whether Office Web Apps was installed on this SharePoint 2010 server?

*Version: SharePoint 2010 Enterprise, on-premise,*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If Office Web Apps is set up and configured for a SharePoint 2010 environment, then it should exist a site collection feature that enables OWA services in every site collection. (Assuming that it is configured and installed correctly with all the service applications).

You can simply run this in PowerShell to determine if the feature exists or not. If it return nothing, OWA is not set up. If it return the feature with it's ID and scope, OWA is configured for the farm.

```
Get-SPFeature | where {$_.displayname -eq "OfficeWebApps"}
```

**EDIT**

You can always check the registry on the server. Click the start button on the server, type run and enter `regedit` in the promt.

Then navigate down to this path: `HK_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`

If OWA is installed, there should be a folder called **Office14.WCSERVER**. You can explore it and see several keys, indicating that OWA is installed.

Comment: when you have time, please see my comment on jp nayak's answer and let me know if you have any additional details to offer.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can check it in Central Administration > Manage servers in farm

You can find the descriptions of `SharePoint Products Installed` and find whether OWA is installed or not

Comment: I agreed that this is a better answer than mine, to early in the morning. +1.

Comment: I did this, and didn't see services with the text "OWA" or "Office Web Apps", however, the Excel Services was installed, which kind of confused me since I thought that was part of Office Web Apps. According to my client, they actively use the Excel Services.
Note that I did run the powershell script provided by @user19952 and it yielded no results.
Based on my findings above, it's still hard to tell if Office Web Apps is installed.

Comment: If in both cases you found no result that means OWA is not installed ,simple.