# SharePoint 2013 SP1 - How do I check for Office Web App?

Tags: sharepoint-server, office-web-apps

How do I confirm if / where we have Office Web App services installed and what server they are running on?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Run the below commands in your SharePoint application server:

```
Get-OfficeWebAppsHost

Get-SPWOPIZone | Get-SPWOPIBinding
```

For more details refer the below MSDN articles:

[Get-OfficeWebAppsFarm](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/officewebapps/get-officewebappsfarm?view=officewebapps-ps)

[Get-OfficeWebAppsHost](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/officewebapps/get-officewebappshost?view=officewebapps-ps)

[Get-SPWOPIBinding](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/get-spwopibinding?view=sharepoint-ps)

Answer (score 0):

You can check it in Central Administration > Manage servers in farm

You can find the descriptions of SharePoint Products Installed and find whether OWA is installed or not.

Similar issue post for your reference:

[How can I tell if Office Web Apps is installed on a SharePoint 2010 server](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/156290/how-can-i-tell-if-office-web-apps-is-installed-on-a-sharepoint-2010-server)